# Why is my webhook code not accessible on HTTPS

Tags: node.js, apache, express, ssl, webhooks

I'm running apache2 based SSL server from a machine running RHEL 8 on AWS. I am trying to deploy a facebook webhook on this server. I am manually testing this, using curl requests. When I put the request in via HTTP, it behaves as expected. However, when the request is made via HTTPS, I get this error message :

`curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`
I need to make it work on HTTPS, as facebook won't allow HTTP only connections.

Any advice would be amazing, thankyou - if I have asked this badly I apologise, this is my first question.

The code for the webhook is as follows:

```
// Imports dependencies and set up http server
const
  express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express().use(bodyParser.json()); // creates express http server

// Sets server port and logs message on success
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, () => console.log('webhook is listening'));

// Creates the endpoint for our webhook
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  let body = req.body;

  // Checks this is an event from a page subscription
  if (body.object === 'page') {

    // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function(entry) {

      // Gets the message. entry.messaging is an array, but
      // will only ever contain one message, so we get index 0
      let webhook_event = entry.messaging[0];
      console.log(webhook_event);
    });

    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
  } else {
    // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }

});

// Adds support for GET requests to our webhook
app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  // Your verify token. Should be a random string.
  let VERIFY_TOKEN = "duckgoesquack"

  // Parse the query params
  let mode = req.query['hub.mode'];
  let token = req.query['hub.verify_token'];
  let challenge = req.query['hub.challenge'];

  // Checks if a token and mode is in the query string of the request
  if (mode && token) {

    // Checks the mode and token sent is correct
    if (mode === 'subscribe' && token === VERIFY_TOKEN) {

      // Responds with the challenge token from the request
      console.log('WEBHOOK_VERIFIED');
      res.status(200).send(challenge);

    } else {
      // Responds with '403 Forbidden' if verify tokens do not match
      res.sendStatus(403);
    }
  }
});
```

I have tried updating my apache conf files - the virtualhosts section is as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
DocumentRoot /var/www/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
DocumentRoot /var/www/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
ServerAlias *.lloydarnoldtestaps.tk
DocumentRoot /var/www/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1337>
ServerName lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
DocumentRoot /var/www/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
DocumentRoot /var/www/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1337>
ServerName www.lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
DocumentRoot /var/www/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you try to run `openssl s_client -connect  www.lloydarnoldtestapps.tk -port 443` 
`-prexit` or `-debug`

Comment: Hi @Yan, did so got this response: ``` 139642581512640:error:0200206E:system library:connect:Connection timed out:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
139642581512640:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=110
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0(ok)```

Comment: There is a padlock showing in my browser, and the certificate is marked as valid there. I'm wondering if maybe I have not set up my config file correctly? If you have any ideas that would be amazing - thankyou ! :) @Yan

Comment: add `-servername www.lloydarnoldtestapps.tk` to the command .. also seems that errno=110 `the server rejects the connection. If this happens, you receive a message such as connect: Connection timed out or connect:errno=110.`

Comment: what happens when you run `openssl s_client -connect lloydarnoldtestapps.tk -port 1337 -server lloydarnoldtestapps.tk -debug`

Comment: what do you mean there is a padlock in the browser?  Are you able to access the site via https in the browser

Comment: Sorry, by 'there is a padlock showing' I meant that HTTPS works and is valid in my browser. I will try those commands now

Comment: The second command you suggested (ending in -debug) was unrecognised, but I ran the former with the addition of the servername flag. The response to that was ``` CONNECTED(00000005) ```, before a series of blocks that said 'reading from' / 'writing to', with bodies of hex. From what I can read of it, the handshake worked - certificate was sent and the console output said it was valid. Are there any particular parts of this output you want? Sorry, it's too long to put in its entirety. Thanks @Yan

Comment: actually I hope you don't mind .. the server `www.lloydarnoldtestapps.tk` is live and i am able to access it .. the certificate presented is fine .. it's let's encrypt .. are you trying to server Node / ExpressJs site?  Are you running node server in the backend?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but is the code for webhook is in `/var/www/lloydarnoldtestapps.tk` directory and you are expecting apache to execute it?  and reply with the challenge when /webhook is called?  Apache will not be able te execute this code you would need node server to run and apache will forward the request and act as a proxy

Comment: Hi @Yan, I don't mind at all - thankyou for testing it. What I'm trying to do is establish a webhook on port 1337 by HTTPS to communicate with facebook messenger. I used Node / ExpressJs to establish a server to run on this port, to which the webhook could attach. I manually tested the connection using cURL and it works (on port 1337) via HTTP but not HTTPS. I'm confused by this, as HTTPS seems to be working generally

Comment: @Yan I am running the index.js file on the apache server - I thought this was the correct deployment method? If not, how should I go about doing this? / Where could I read about methods. Thankyou so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what's happening.
`curl -vv  -X POST  https://www.lloydarnoldtestapps.tk` 
response is from apache `Server: Apache/2.4.37`

When running `curl -vv  -X POST  http://www.lloydarnoldtestapps.tk:1337/webhook`
Response is from express  `X-Powered-By: Express`

I think when you started express first and it bind to `port 1337` and when you ran apache it actually wasn't able to bind so that's why you are receiving `200` when sending a request to `port 1337`

You cannot return index.js from apache.  You would use apache as a reverse proxy and proxy request from AWS (HTTPS) -> Apache (HTTP) -> Express.  This way apache will terminate https and make the request via http to express.

Look into Proxy and ProxyPass for apache and tutorial on reverse proxy to nodejs server.

Check out this post [ProxyPass apache https to a node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865193/proxypass-apache-https-to-a-node-server)

Specifically these directives

```
  ProxyPass / https://example.com:4433/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com:4433 /
```

Post back if you have any questions.

Comment: Thankyou so much - I will try that first thing tomorrow and let you know. Thankyou for your help!

Comment: I looked into using reverse proxies, and have found a solution. Thankyou so so much for your help - you have saved me a huge amount of time and improved my understanding of web applications !

Comment: @LloydArnold That's great! Happy coding!