# Can I server a single NodeJS page to an existing web server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a website running that is using a lightweight https server. I have a NodeJS web app that I want to add to this website. I can create JS files and navigate to them in my site but I have not worked with NodeJS before.

If I had a NodeJS app, could it still work off of the existing web server or would the NodeJS need to act as the web server itself? I just need to get all of the post data in the NodeJS app if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ProxyPass apache https to a node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865193/proxypass-apache-https-to-a-node-server)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'd need to configure the existing web server to pass the request through to your Node.js process and then send the response back. That is, it would need to act as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) for a specific path. It's entirely possible to configure most HTTP servers to do that (for example, [for Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html), [for Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)). How specifically you do it depends on what web server software you're using, but that's the term to look for in their documenation.